# Get a "Response header" Cookie from angular $http POST request

Tags: angularjs, cookies, couchdb

I'm writing a small app using angular.
I need to access a couch database. I only have a user in that DB.
Using cURL commands I can request a session cookie to that database and that use that cookie to request a specific document.

When in angular code I use:

```
$http.post(url, data).then(...);
```

Where 'data' has username and password, I can see the cookie using chrome (like in this image [chrome dev tool output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuSWd.png)), but in a code, I can't access it.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How did you use cookie to access the database?

Comment: With curl I've made: curl -vX GET https://couchdb.cloudno.de/myDB/my_id  --cookie myCookie.  With angular, because I can't access it, I didn't try yet

Answer (score 2):

You can not access an [`HttpOnly`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookie using script in browser due to security reasons. It can only be accessed on server.

If you need to include cookies in cross domain requests use `withCredentials` in the request. See `$http` docs

Answer (score 0):

$http.post returns a response with a property:

> headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.

So you should be able to do something like

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.headers('set-cookie'));
});
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: I've already try that, but the console.log return 'null'. In the image I've expanded the response object and it only has 2 headers ('Accept' and 'Content-type')

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `response.headers('set-cookie')`
For the crossdomain situation, the server has to send 
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: set-cookie` header to make the custom headers visible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers